# Laravel is returning double or float as integer

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I have a model where i am saving ratings and datatype for rating is double. It is saving values in database in correct format for example 5.00 but when i fetch this it returns as 5(as integer) it returns correct for values like 5.10 or any other having effective value after decimal point but for values like 1.00, 2.00, 3.00 it returns only integer nothing after decimal point but i need everything exactly like it is saved in Database.

Already applied protected $cats array but no luck.
Already using native driver.

Answer (score 2):

You should cast it to proper type:

```
protected $casts = [
    'rating' => 'double'
];
```

I you are using decimal:

```
protected $casts = [
    'rating' => 'decimal:2'
];
```

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting)

Answer (score 0):

One easy way you can use php function `number_format`

```
number_format($number, 2, '.', ',')
```

// 2 = decimal places  |  '.' = decimal seperator  |  ',' = thousand seperator -> if you need...that here you don't need so use:

```
number_format($number, 2, '.', '')
```

for more examples visit [Number Format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this in your model:

```
protected $casts = [
    'attr1' => 'float',
];
```